# Python not loading the json file

Tags: python

I am load a json file in another variable for show the type of variable. But the problem occurred that the json file was not found by python. In addition i am also keep my json file with same folder in python folder.

[image]

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Your editor says the file is named "076 data.json"?

Comment: Your file is called 076 data.json, please post your code not screenshots in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file name is `076 data.json`

rename your file to `data.json` and the code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the filename is different, it is `076 data.json` and you are passing `data.json`.